# Dynamically created textbox in ajax returns null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following is the code in which textbox is created

```
<input type="text" class="enter_comment"  value='comments' id='comm<?php echo $row['p_id'];?>'/>
<input type='button' value='enter' class='cbtn' id='<?php echo $row['p_id'];?>'>
```

And here is the button click code in `ajax`.

```
$(".cbtn").click(
    function(e){
        alert("here");
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var c="#comm"+id;   

        var comment = $(c).attr("value");
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $.post("comments.php",{id:id, comment:comment},function(e){         
            $('.comment').append(e);
        }       
    );      
});
```

The problem is that when I try to get value of text box , it returns null. Even when I tried to set value through innerHTML, it said : "Cannot set property of null".

Above mentioned code is in AJAX in the same file. And ids of text boxes are set by value in database

Comment: where is variable vv?

Comment: That was supposed to be comment. Edited it

Comment: event.stopImmediatePropagation();
alert(id);
alert(comment);   try this alert it lost the id and comment values after the statment  event.stopImmediatePropagation(); . so it sends blang id and blank comment in post.

Comment: I suggest using `data` attribute to hold additional information. You passed the event as `e` in `function(e)` and later you used `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` ???

Comment: @RNmalek still not working

Comment: and I added the default value comments. Now it is just returning comments instead of the text that I entered in text field

Comment: Try changing `$(c).attr("value");` to `$(c).val();` @puffles

Comment: @frz3993 thank you, it worked ^_^